# C# set get not working first click using forms

Tags: c#, forms, get, set

I am building a simple text editor program. When the text has been edited a window shows up and asking if you want to save the file. This has been implemented using forms and booleans stored in the popup window.
If i press yes, no or cancel the first time the setters doesn't work. But if i press the second the setters work perfectly. Why doesn't it work the first time?
Code for the popup window.

```cs
public bool Exit { set; get; }
public bool Save { set; get; }
public bool _Open { set; get; }
```

```cs
case ("Yes"):
{
    if (form1.Operation() == "Exit")
    {
        Exit = true; //Bool that tells the program to exit.
        MessageBox.Show(Exit.ToString()); //This prints the correct value
    }
    Save = true; //Bool that states if file should be saved.
    return;
}
```

Code for main textedit window. Example with a user pressed the exit button.

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Form3 form3 = new Form3(); //the popup class.
    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
        {
            if (_edited)
            {
                _operation = "Exit";
                form3.ShowDialog();

                MessageBox.Show(form3.Exit.ToString()); //Always false on first entry?
                if (form3.Exit)
                {
                    if (form3.Save)
                    {
                        Save();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your question you say "yes, no or cancel" but in the second block of code it seems to only set `Exit = true` for the "Yes" case. Could this be the issue?

You could try setting breakpoints and debugging the code to be able to figure what is going on. If you remove auto properties and add backing field manually, you could also set breakpoints to see when the setters are called. You could write your Exit like this:

```
private bool _exit;
public bool Exit
{
    get => _exit;
    set
    {
        _exit = value;
    }
}
```

This would allow you to set a breakpoint and see exactly when the setter is called.
If you need help with debugging, please provide some information about which code editor you are using.